# New ftp user created and now I can't access website over my wifi network

Tags: networking, ftp, php

I have created a new FTP user and now I can't access my website over my wifi address. I have checked if it is banned/blocked in Cpanel or in the application and everything was good.

As soon as I go over my phone or connect my laptop to my mobile data I can access the website easily.

Did you have this issue?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you connect to the FTP over wifi? And if you disconnect the FTP, can you connect to the server? may be a connection limit.

Comment: Have you tried removing the user? Does that restore access to the site?